# How does this way of computing array-length work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i am new to c++ and stumbled upon this way of computing the length of an array with pointers which i don't exactly understand. I looked everywhere but nowhere seems to be an explanation on how it works, i just heard that it's supposed to be a bad way of computing array length but why is that and how does it even work?

The code would look something like this:

```
int array[4] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
//...
int length = *(&array + 1) - array
```

As far as i've tried, it really seems to work, but i don't exactly understand why. I know a bit of pointer logic but this statement seems really odd to me, because you're essentially taking the address of the array (the first element i suppose) and adding one to it (i can imagine that that will give you the address after the last element, but then i don't understand why you would dereference it). And what confuses me most, is that this all gets substracted with the array itself?! Without an index or anything.

It would really help when someone would be able to explain that to me, and why it's supposed to be bad exactly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> &array
> ```

This is a pointer to the object `array`. It is a singular object of an array type.

> ```
> &array + 1
> ```

Adding a number to a pointer produces a pointer to a successive sibling of the object in an array of objects. Adding 1 produces the next sibling. For purposes of this pointer arithmetic, singular objects are treated as array of single object. Hence, adding 1 is allowed and it produces a pointer past the end of the figurative array.

> ```
> *(&array + 1)
> ```

Strictly speaking, this indirects through a pointer past the end, and it may be argued that the behaviour of the program is undefined.

But let's assume that's not a problem. The indirection operation produces an lvalue to the (non-existent) object at the address after the array.

> ```
> *(&array + 1) - array
> ```

Here, the operands of the subtraction are lvalues to arrays. One is the actual array and the other is a hypothetical sibling element in a hypothetical array of arrays. In this case, those arrays implicitly convert to a pointer to first element of the respective arrays.

Technically, the subtraction between the converted pointers is undefined because they are pointers to elements of separate arrays, so arguably the behaviour of the program is undefined for yet another reason.

But let's assume that's not a problem. The result of subtracting pointers to two elements of the same array produces the distance of the elements. The distance between first elements of adjacent arrays is exactly the number of elements in the first array.

> why it's supposed to be bad exactly.

Notice the parts in previous sections that say behaviour of the program is undefined. That's bad.

Also, you had a problem understanding what it does. That's bad.

Recommended way to get the size of an array is to use `std::size(array)`.

Comment: @Aconcagua `Problem rather is that we are subtracting pointers of different type... ` There's no such problem. Both `array` and `*(&array + 1)` are lvalues of same type: `int[4]`. They both decay to `int*`. After the decay, the subtracted pointers are of same type. But they point to first element of different arrays.

Comment: @Aconcagua The standard defines pointer subtraction for pointers to elements of an array. It does not define what pointer subtraction means when operands are not to elements of the same array. It's undefined. `arr2d[0][0]` and `arr2d[1][0]` are not elements of the same array.

Comment: @eerorika   In C, what you say is correct.  In C++, the calculation of a pointer one past the end of an array (of any type) is explicitly allowed and valid, but dereferencing such a pointer gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter One-past-the-end pointer is valid in C as well – and not dereferencable alike. Interesting question now is if a pointer to the first element of a succeeding sub-array is identical to the one-past-the-end pointer of the preceding one. Because if so – not only de-facto, but backed by the standard – this length calculation would get legal for all but the very last sub-array in a 2D array...

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the code is to first pretend there is a second array of four `int` (called `array2`for sake of discussion) located in memory immediately after the end of `array`.   I say "pretend" because `array2` does not actually exist.

Based on that pretense, the logic of the code is then;

1. `&array` is a pointer to `array`.   It has type `int (*)[4]` (more verbosely described for humans as "a pointer to an array of four `int`");
2. `&array + 1` is a pointer to `array2`;
3. Dereferencing that pointer i.e. calculating `*(&array + 1)` gives a (reference to) `array2`;
4. In the expression `*(&array + 1) - array`, the terms `*(&array + 1)` and `array` are each implicitly converted to an `int *`.   The values of these pointers are `&array2[0]` and `&array[0]` respectively.   So the expression `*(&array + 1) - array` is equivalent to `&array2[0] - &array[0]`;
5. Since `array2` is located in memory immediately after the last element of `array`, `&array2[0]` is equal to `&array[4]`  (i.e. to the address of a non-existent `array[4]`).   Subtracting two pointers of type `int *` gives the number of `int`s between them  i.e. `&array[4] - &array[0]` gives a value `4` (of type `std::ptrdiff_t`);
6. Since `length` has type `int`, that `std::ptrdiff_t` with value `4` is converted to an int`, i.e. to the value` 4`.

That's the logic that (presumably) the compiler (or compilers) you are testing with is using.

The problem - i.e. why people consider it bad - is because `array2` and `array[4]` do not actually exist.  So - according to the standards - step 3 above gives undefined behaviour.   All of the subsequent points (which mention the non-existent `array2` or the non-existent `array[4]`) also involve undefined behaviour.   The meaning of undefined behaviour is that the standards do not define what happens - so compilers are NOT required to implement the logic of the code.

A way to get the size of `array` without giving undefined behaviour is simply `length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` since the `sizeof` operator examines only the type of its arguments (and doesn't evaluate them) so avoids undefined behaviour.  `sizeof(array)` gives the size (in bytes) of an array of four `int`, and `sizeof(array[0])` gives the size (in bytes) of a single `int`, so dividing them gives `4`.

**Advanced note:**  The limitations of the approach using `sizeof` is that it doesn't work in the presence of pointer conversion.  For example, if `array` is actually a pointer (which happens if a raw array is passed as an argument to a function) the calculation will not (necessarily) give a value of `4`.

Comment: The same limitation applies for the pointer arithmetic approach: `int* p = ...; size_t s = *(&p + 1) - p;`, doesn't it?

Comment: I can't remember the standard requiring two separate variables being declared one after another not having gaps in between – which is the case for array members, though. Maybe better consider `array` as part of a 2d array instead?

Comment: @Aconcagua  For your first comment:   If you mean that calculating `*(&p + 1)` gives undefined behaviour, then yes.   For your second:  the point is that the expression is dereferencing a pointer to something that doesn't exist - it's the same logic whether we assume a 2D array or pretend there is a second array immediately in memory after the one we have defined  (since a 2D array is simply an array of arrays, and arrays are contiguous).   Either way, the standard does not require anything there.

Comment: I meant that it won't result in correct size either – but the UB actually is even worse...